# What are Travis-CI API rate limits

Tags: travis-ci

Since [attack on its API](https://www.traviscistatus.com/incidents/3f8mwqxbh127), travis-ci introduced limits on its REST API . We have a monitoring system that queries this API to get statuses of some projects, this is now hitting the roof. This has also an impact on the web interface.
What are the limits?

Comment: I think you should ask directly Travis support. Still, your question is interesting. +1

Comment: I had also the occasion to ask the Travis support. I understood that, as they just introduced them, the limits have not reach the definitive state yet and may still move. Though, this commit gives an idea in which direction they're working: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-api/commit/b59fa6cd9404e15c5e21d1c9b97f64ebfeb9ce4f

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the limit is 10/hour on .org, and 50/hour on .com.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017 August, the current limit on `.org` are (as coded in https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-api/blob/master/lib/travis/api/attack.rb):

Blacklist:

- <2 authentications (`POST /auth/github`) within 5 minutes, otherwise banned for 5 hours.
- <10 `POST` requests within 30 seconds, otherwise banned for 1 hour

Throttling:

- <1 authentication per minute
- <500 requests per minute when not authenticated
- <2000 requests per minute when authenticated with GitHub token